# How can I sort this json data in php?

Tags: php, json

How can I sort this json data in php?

 
I'm trying to  display only the **menu__item_name** in foreach it's working.
but I don't knw how to sort data.
   I want to sort this JSON array by `menu_item_sort`?

How can I do that?
I'm using the below code to display  **menu__item_name**

```
$obj = json_decode($list->mi_des);
$Name =$obj->{'menu__item_name'};


$arr_name = array($Name);
$arr_name_imp = implode(" ",$arr_name);
$arr_name_exp = explode("|",$arr_name_imp);

foreach($arr_name_exp as $i =>$key) {
    echo $key;
}
```

The data

```
{
  "menu__item_name":"test1|test2|test3",
  "menu_item_price":"775.00|100|30",
  "menu_item_description":"Melon Ball |Big mac|cocke",
  "menu_item_sort":"1|3|2",
  "menu_item_status":"1|1|1",
  "menu_item_display":"1|1|0"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck? Also: *what* data are you sorting? You mentioned the `menu_item_sort` property, which has a few numbers. What is it supposed to be applied to? As written, this is unclear. Please edit your question to clarify, and to show your work.

Comment: I think you have come across one of the great examples of why storing data in delimited strings is such a bad idea

Comment: Ok, so... you are referring to a delimited string as an "array" - hence the confusion. This seems like a really odd way of storing data, as JSON, which already has the notion of subdocuments and arrays. You seem to have built something like a table within your document, but with data divided up across multiple properties. Is there a reason why you created such a document? As structured, you would need to deconstruct each delimited string, then join elements of each separate string into their correct objects.

Answer (score 0):

Decode json string, explode each array element and do loop as per `"menu_item_sort"`. hope this would help.

```
$str = '{
"menu__item_name":"test1|test2|test3",
  "menu_item_price":"775.00|100|30",
  "menu_item_description":"Melon Ball |Big mac|cocke",
  "menu_item_sort":"1|3|2",
  "menu_item_status":"1|1|1",
  "menu_item_display":"1|1|0"
}';

$strArr = json_decode($str);

$menu__item_name_arr = explode('|', $strArr->menu__item_name);
$menu_item_price_arr = explode('|', $strArr->menu_item_price);
$menu_item_description_arr = explode('|', $strArr->menu_item_description);
$menu_item_sort_arr = explode('|', $strArr->menu_item_sort);
$menu_item_status_arr = explode('|', $strArr->menu_item_status);
$menu_item_display_arr = explode('|', $strArr->menu_item_display);

foreach($menu_item_sort_arr as $item){
    $key = $item - 1; //array index start from 0
    $finalArr['menu__item_name'][] = isset($menu__item_name_arr[$key]) ? $menu__item_name_arr[$key]  : '' ;
    $finalArr['menu_item_price'][] = isset($menu_item_price_arr[$key]) ? $menu_item_price_arr[$key]  : '' ;
    $finalArr['menu_item_description'][] = isset($menu_item_description_arr[$key]) ? $menu_item_description_arr[$key]  : '';
    $finalArr['menu_item_sort'][] = isset($menu_item_sort_arr[$key]) ? $menu_item_sort_arr[$key]  : '' ;
    $finalArr['menu_item_status'][] = isset($menu_item_status_arr[$key]) ? $menu_item_status_arr[$key]  : '' ;
    $finalArr['menu_item_display'][] = isset($menu_item_display_arr[$key]) ? $menu_item_display_arr[$key] : '';
}

foreach($finalArr as $k => $arr){
    $newArr[$k] = implode('|', $arr);
}
$sortedJson = (object) $newArr;
print_r($sortedJson);
echo json_encode($sortedJson);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/HCWV5)